# EF automatically update EDMX file

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I was wondering if there is a way to update the EDMX file in programmaticaly (in c#). I need to switch to database from different versions which requires the model to change frequently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a reason you should do it manually. What happens when a column is removed or has its name or datatype changed and your app crashes?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Sorry for my late response, been busy lately. With my EF context I have methods that get everything from 1 table. The problem is that this table is frequently updated. The version at the customer misses 2 columns whilst my edmx model does have those columns. That throws the exception. Any idea how I can solve this problem? I liked the idea from @Victor Hugo Terceros where i would make several models with each a different version. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So... your app doesn't use these two missing columns? You could just use direct SQL instead of LINQ / EF but that will likely cause more problems. Fundamentally, this is a bad way to run software deployment. Any workaround to this just adds complexity and risk of bugs. You basically need to add the two columns to your client site and get all schemas inline.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework DataBase first creates an XML (EDMX) file and a set of classes linked to it, this way you access to the model generated (tables, views, stored procedures) in your code.

So when you say update the model in run time, you basically want to re-generate a set of classes in run time and I don't think that is possible.

If you want to access to different versions of a DataBase (maybe different customers) you can do it at a db level creating Stored Procedures and using them in code. Or generating one model per DB.